# Archives not showing up in Organizer for Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4

I'm trying to create an IPA in Xcode 4, much like the person who asked this question:

[Xcode 4: create IPA file instead of .xcarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive)

So--I got my Archive completing successfully--supposedly.  It dumps .xcarchive files for the project in its destination folder.  But these archives don't show up in my Organizer window.  So I can't share them as described in the above question to create the IPA.

There are no errors in the archiving process--they seem to be signed OK.  So why aren't the archives showing up in the archive panel on the Organizer? Is there some step I'm missing...or obscure setting I need to modify?

Comment: Same problem over here as well. Plus old archives from previous version are gone.

Comment: Had the same problem. Didnt config the Skip Install Flag properly. (Had them mixed up somehow) Now it worked. Yay

Comment: @Helge Becker: What did you do to make it work?

Comment: Now, if you had this issue recently (Dec 2016) then it could also be because your OS has upgraded and your XCode version didn't. I saw this happen for OS X El Capitan - 10.11.16 and they had to upgrade Xcode to 8.2

Comment: Your archive might be **corrupt**. Double click on the created archive from Finder to see. You might have embedded something into your project that made the archive corrupted.

Answer (score 193):

EDIT (Incorporated all comments to a single answer)

Try one of the following (or all)

1. Instead of using Build For -> Archive, in the product menu just use archive. It will show up then.
2. In the scheme editor, edit the scheme and go to the Archive tab, make sure the check box for show in Organizer is checked.
3. In the archive tab in the scheme editor check the build configuration used for archiving. Make sure it has the right entitlements file & certificates.
4. In the build settings switch Skip Install -> Release to NO, for the build settings used for archiving.
5. Make sure the archives folder and XCode project files are inside the same shared folder if network drive is used. I took me a few days to finally figure this out as I placed my XCode source files from a Windows shared folder, but the Archives folder is on the local Mac, which caused archives not picked up by Organizer.

Thanks to @Smikey & @Ralph B & @Scott McMillin

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  Both Build For -> Archive and Archive didn't work for me.  But I took out the entitlements.plist I had from my 3.X version--double checked that the scheme used in the Archive build was using the right cert....and it showed up.  Took me ALL DAY to figure it out though.

Comment: Hmm didn't work for me. Tried both methods of archiving, deleted all copies of entitlements.plist, tripple checked the certs... Still no archives appearing :( Anything else you tried that may have had anything to do with it?

Comment: Well I seem to have fixed it. In the build settings, in the deployment section, I switched Skip Install -> Release to NO. I'd set it to YES following the Apple advice... guess that was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Try going to Edit Scheme... and select the Archive tab. Make sure the checkbox for show in organizer is there. Also check that the right build configuration is used. If that doesn't help, I read some where that naming the archive might help so try that as well.

Comment: Same problem here; followed @Smirkey's advice and changed Skip Install back to NO and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, same here. I'd originally put Skip Install -> Yes (according to Apple docs) but had to set Skip Install -> No (all configurations) to get the archives to appear in Organizer - Archives (so you can access the Validate, Share, Submit buttons).

Comment: My problem was not fixed by this solution, but it was fixed from Smikey's suggestion of settting "Skip Install" to NO.  Thank you!

Comment: Setting Skip Install to NO fixed this for me.

Comment: Step 1 (Archive instead of Build For -> Archive) did the trick for me.  I have xcode 4.2.  I do not see a skip install anywhere.  I looked in the Targets window under Deployment.  It's not there.

Comment: +1  Archive instead of Build For Archive did the trick. THERE *IS* a delay of about one minute before it shows up in the Organizer (running dual-core macmini here).  It makes sense now: sometimes we just build without running don't we? :-)  It was good to check all those other settings though.  Note iOS Deployment Target can be set differently for project and target!

Comment: Also, if you are using **CocoaPods** like me, you should set proper **Code Signing Identity** in **Build Settings** of Pods project.

Answer (score 67):

This is based on another answer from a similar question which can be found at [Archive does not appear in xcode4 organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280914/archive-does-not-appear-in-xcode4-organizer)

I take no credit for this answer, but this together with the suggestions from Ron fixed the problem for me.

For the "Release" configuration do the following:

Set "Skip Install" to YES on your project

Set "Skip Install" to NO on your application target

Set "Skip Install" to YES on all static library targets that are included

Choose Product -> Archive from the menu.

This also worked for me, and according to the original answer poster, is based on advice from the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: Only this answer did the trick! Probably because I mixed up the project and target settings for "Skip Install". Thank you!

Comment: You are a legend, this worked for me after too many hours of mucking around with build settings...

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem... I had mistakenly set "Installation Directory" (`INSTALL_PATH`) to an empty string in my Build Settings. Removing this setting and using the default `/Applications` solved my issue.

Comment: None of the above answers did it. Xcode just changed this value out from under me, I assume, as archives were working fine and suddenly stopped. Thanks for this!

Comment: Same here, this is a working fix. Glad I didn't give up on the lower voted answers.

Comment: Reference about "Installation Directory" (the url is strange): http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/210-Building_Products/building.html#build-locations

Comment: Thanks for this. I have no idea why my iPad app needed this set, but it did fix the issue :)

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.

Comment: I also had to set `INSTALL_ROOT` back to its default.

Comment: I was trying to archive a cef project. And this really works for me.

Answer (score 8):

One more thing to check:
Search for the "Installation Directory" in your Build Settings (All) and make sure it's set to "/Applications".

Answer (score 8):

Yes! Finally. I too was stuck on this for 2 days!
I should have checked here first!

Skip Install ... moved it to NO and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where the distribution compiled and signed fine, but never showed up in the Archive tab.  Turns out I needed to attach a device to get it to build a "real" iOS build.  Once I attached my device, I ran Product -> Archive and it showed up as expected.

Answer (score 4):

None of the suggestions here worked for me, including setting "Skip Install" to NO... until I set "Installation Directory" to something other than the blank default value. (I used "/Applications" but other values like "/usr/bin" would be fine too.) Then lo and behold, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the advice. I finally ended up with my archive using the skip install yes for the project and no for the targets. Thank you so much. Compared with others, this only took me about 3 hours, but I wish I would have found this thread earlier (now it's 1.45 am).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have facing the same issue in my project. After archiving my project, organizer window in not open. So i had done this. And it will works for me. Hopefully it will helps you.

1. Select your project -> In the build settings switch Skip Install -> Release to NO, for the build settings used for archiving.
   After that you can archive your project properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem ! And resolved :)

I add this into my info.plist file:

create a new property "Bundle versions string, short" and provide the same version number as for "Bundle version" property. (Thanks to Rahul Choudhary, in his post "XCode 4 Archive Version Unspecified")

Answer (score 1):

I tried them all and still nothing worked.
Then I reconnected my iPad, reselected 
Skip Install = NO for release and archive
...Build failed for code sign
Reselected Scheme iPad, rather than simulator
Build succeeded.

Not sure this will work for anyone else, but I've have just spent 5 hours going thru all the hints, and tripped up on this success. I don't think it clears it up, and hope Apple gets this squared away. In the year 2011, this is just absurd.

Comment: Ok now it works. Reselected Skip Install = NO for Debug, Release AND Distribution. Reselected the distribution certificate for the distribution builds ( even though it already showed the correct ones). And of course reset the submission state to 'Ready for Upload'. Validate and Submitted thru XCode Organizer. I have made dozens of updates to my product, but now XCode 4.0 has created a nightmare.

Comment: This is the one that did it for me.  Even though it goes against Apple's instructions, I couldn't get anything to show in the Archive list without setting Skip Install to NO for Release (click project name -> target -> build settings -> under Deployment -> maxmize Skip Install -> Release=NO)

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the solution worked, instead it was a simple cause: folder permissions. 
Make sure staff group has: Read & Write permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the standard options listed in the first answer worked. I noticed that "installation paths" was empty. I nicely created 4 paths: `<somepath>/Dbg`, `<somepath>/Dbg/Ins`, `<somepath>/Rel` and `<somepath>/Rel/Ins` and set the 4 directories (build debug, install debug, build release and install release) to the 4 newly created directories. I also set the famous "skill install" option to no in all 4 instances (product & target, debug & release). I then ran a product > clean and product > archive. Eh Voila. The release now showed up in the archives section of the organizer.

Comment: Funnily enough, even after setting all those paths, the actual archive was created in '/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-08-13/<project_name>.xcarchive'. In any case, not that it matters, since I could now upload directly from the organizer to the app store now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I upgraded my existing product, I didn't have all the icons listed in the Info.plist.

So I added both the "Icon files" and "Icon files (iOS 5)" to the .plist. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Xcode 4.6.1 but with the twist that the Archive did show quickly in the Organizer window but suddenly disappeared.

Solved this problem by commenting out the last two lines:

```
echo "Moving Archive: $ARCHIVE_PATH to $PROJECT_DIR"
#rm -rf "$PROJECT_DIR/XX.xcarchive"
#mv -f "$ARCHIVE_PATH" "$PROJECT_DIR/XX.xcarchive"
```

This via "Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme - Archive - Post Actions".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the OP and everyone on this thread.

I had the same issue, but had a different solution.

If you keep your archives on an external drive, and if the drive happens to get disconnected for some reason, in /Volumes the drive may be remounted at "DRIVENAME 1" instead of "DRIVENAME". Everything looks normal except in the /Volumes folder, you'll see a file with the name DRIVENAME. Disconnect your drive properly, rmdir the DRIVENAME file and reconnect.

The drive will connect under its original name and Xcode will be able to see everything again.

Spent about 5 hours on that. ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Carthage, there was a recently fixed issue that caused this: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1259

The fix is simply to update carthage (>= 0.16.1) and re-run the archive.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, issue was due using fastlane as root. It set up the Archive file in the Archives folder as root, so when I tried to create the build from XCode, it didn't couldn't write to this folder.
No message was shown by XCode

Answer (score 0):

For anyone working with *flutter* -

I had the same issue after running `flutter build ipa`. I solved it using moving the archived file from flutter path:
`build/ios/archive/MyApp.xcarchive` to *Xcode* archive dir: `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-03-30`
(I created a folder with the desired date).

Answer (score 0):

Change the target device to all rather than a specific device and it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Organiser was empty after try every here recommended settings, also it was impossible and do 'Product > Archive' but... Only when device connected on cable and app run then 'Archive' show up.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding write permissions to the Archives folder at
`Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` using `chmod` command.

Comment: Curious why you didn't already have write permission for the Archives folder. It's writable by default.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to switch the scheme from simulator to Generic iOS Device. This gave me the option to access archive.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

i think it not really big a problem
archive does not appear if your using simulator
it was easily fixed by selecting your device in the edit scheme,
then click archive in the archive tab

no complicated steps

Answer (score -5):

I ran Product -> Archive and it showed up as expected.

Comment: The answer does not suggest any solution to the question asked. Do you have any ideas how to fix the issue?