# Archive does not appear in xcode4 organizer

Tags: archive, xcode4, organizer

I am trying to submit an app to iTunes using the new xcode4.

I followed the apple instructions but after doing product> archive, I still do not see anything in my organizer.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I got the same problem.  Took me whole night to solve.  The doc gave the wrong instruction - therefore all your archives are created but their size is zero.  You can verify this by going to their directory (...derived data...)

Anyway, in the "Skip Install", set the value for "Release" as "NO" (the help doc told you the opposite).  Once you set it to "NO", archive again.  You'll immediately see your app showing up in the archive organizer.

Comment: Gosh thank you very much! I will try it out. U r so generous.

Comment: Just in case someone else sees this, this solution did not work for me

Comment: Worked for me... I don't know. I'm pretty sure they could make the whole upload process simpler, but I do like that it's almost all handled from within the app, instead of having to find the binary, zip it up, launch application loader, and jump through hoop to upload it. Now if they could allow you to skip the whole iTunesConnect part to add a new version...

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. When I saw: "Some idiot at Apple caused all this confusion. Stupid." i loled, because you are totally right. :)

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  Typical Apple FUBAR documentation.  Again.  The time cost of their docs is incredible.

Answer (score 31):

For the "Release" configuration do the following:

Set "Skip Install" to YES on your project

Set "Skip Install" to NO on your application target

Set "Skip Install" to YES on all static library targets that are included

Choose Product -> Archive from the menu.

This worked for me, and is based on advice from the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: Still not working for me. App builds fine on device with no errors. Device is plugged in when I go build->archive Project and Target settings are both "Skip Install" set to NO It's the release configuration. Code signings are correct. Scheme: - Build Configuration is Release
- Archive name: set to my app name
- Options: Reveal in Organizer set to checked

Comment: I have attempted all variations of the above and didn't get any archives; must be just me

Comment: I have attempted everything here as well - no luck. @zardon Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Changed to value to NO on Target Skip Install and this worked for me. Checked values on Project and it was set to Default to YES. I agree! Some moronic space case from apple screw this one up! Thanks Apps4U

Answer (score 2):

For me setting the above plus setting `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` to "Yes" made archiving possible.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to restart my Xcode in order for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Used tutorial from this link: http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html.

Instructions for Skip Install suggested set to YES. Archive did not show in Xcode | Window | Organizer.

Reset Skip Install to its default NO. Archive is now showing in Organizer.

Answer (score 1):

I had to switch the scheme from using the ipad 6.0 simulator to iOS Device.  I then had the option to archive.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode after you archive. The archive will now appear in Organiser.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to set the correct distribution profile at "Code Signing Identity" under build setting.

Set it to the correct Distribution Profile ( First, you need to get it at developer.apple.com/ios )

Answer (score 0):

Besides the correct 'Code Signing Identity' and 'Skill install' configuration, you must also check if your Install directories in Project and Targets are `$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do "Product | Archive" and then it showed up for me.

Answer (score 0):

No luck with 'Skip Install'. 
In my case I created a new schmeme and assigned my target - and it appears on organizer.

My fault was that I had multiple schemes and multiple targets, some targets (even in divergent project files but all together in the same workspace) had the same name. I renamed the target files and recreated the needed schemes and archive now shows up in organizer.