# Archiving Ipad App?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have a developers account and tested my iPad app in my iPad, now i want to sent the app to US for testing, i don't know how to archive it, the developer shows the following steps,

To archive your application . . .
From the Scheme pop-up menu, choose a scheme.
From the same menu, choose Edit Active Scheme to display the scheme dialog.
In the left column, select Archive.
Choose a build configuration.
Specify a name for the archive and click OK.
Choose Product > Archive

But The Scheme popup is showing only simulators but not Scheme popup menu.

Can anyone explain me how to get it.

Comment: What does "send the app to US" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you clicking the name of the project on the left side of the arrow? This should pop up a menu with the options:
Edit Scheme...
New Scheme...
Manage Schemes..

Comment: hi jay thanks it worked, i edited the Scheme.  but the file is not showing in organiser Archive, can you help me out

Comment: in your build settings under deployment do you have skip install set to yes or no?

Comment: perhaps take a look at this question, if it doesn't solve your problem you should ask a new question for this issue and be sure to hit the green check if i helped you with your scheme menu problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280914/archive-does-not-appear-in-xcode4-organizer