# Archiving in Xcode produces no archives

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I tried to build my app both for adhoc distribution and release, and either way, the archives don't show up in Organizer. The build succeeds and the app and dsym file show up as expected, but no archives - Organizer says "No Archives."

Other notes:

1) I don't think it's related to the SKIP_INSTALL property in Settings. I had that issue months ago, and corrected it. I also went through my Build Settings and verified SKIP_INSTALL was set to No for the static libraries again, just to be sure - [Archive does not appear in xcode4 organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280914/archive-does-not-appear-in-xcode4-organizer)

2) I can build debug and run the app just fine.

3) I build apps from several user accounts on this iMac, and the other user accounts generate archives OK, for other apps.

I have tried searching, but I am stuck. I was wondering if I should try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4 it might help you.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and none of the solutions you've already tried helped me either. I found this answer [Archives not showing up in Organizer for XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4/8102602#8102602) which had the fix for me.

In short, my Installation Directory under the Deployment section in my Build Settings was blank. I set it to "/Applications" and was able to see my archives again.

That being said, I am working on another project where this field is blank and I am having no issues. It could be that XCode just barfed and needed this field changed to SOMETHING and that I could have just as easily changed it back from /Applications to a blank value. Or, alternatively, setting the blank value in my current project to "/Applications" could keep things working fine. But, if it ain't broke...And in the former case, it *was* broke, and changing this field worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention that you checked the default location where Xcode stores the archives. You could double-check it under Xcode > Preferences ... > Locations.

If that does not help, I would try renaming the directories related to Xcode under the account where Xcode is not archiving correctly. I.e.:

~/Library/Application Support/Developer
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer

I would also suggest to copy the project that Xcode is not archiving over to a different account and trying to archive it from there. That would help pinning down if the problem is project-related or account-related.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use command line as an alternative?  Try this script, even if command line alone doesn't suit your needs, maybe it will shed some light on what's wrong?  See if you can create a valid ipa file with this script (you'll need to populate the variables with paths specific to your system):

```
cd "${PROJDIR}"
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration Release
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  exit 1
fi
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa"
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me in Xcode 7.1. while archiving an iOS Ionic Cordova app.

My problem was caused by not having the correct Scheme selected. There were two schemes available under Product > Scheme, one was my-app-name and the other was 'CordovaLib' which was selected and caused empty archives to be created with sweet FA appearing in the Organizer (and no error messages or anything).

To actually change the scheme to my-app-name I had to do it from the weirdly designed dropdown on the top left of Xcode main interface. It's not possible to change it from the Product > Scheme menu even though it looks like you can.

Once I changed the scheme my archives started working and appearing in the Organizer.

This link has further info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-XCODE_SUCCESSFULLY_ARCHIVED_MY_APPLICATION__BUT_THE_ARCHIVES_ORGANIZER_DOES_NOT_LIST_MY_ARCHIVE

Comment: **Someone give this man a cookie!** This answer saved what remained of the hair I was pulling out. Worked _perfectly_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe has ever happened to me but, in my opinion the solution should be found in the Edit Scheme option of the Product menu, there you can find the Archive section and its configuration.

Check the option Reveal Archive in Organizer, the Build configuration, etc...

I hope that this may help you...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are building a scheme that uses a Build Configuration that uses a Distribution certificate, and also that you aren't building for the Simulator but for the device (you don't have to have one plugged in, but you need to choose that as the destination).

Then, go to the Product menu and choose Archive.

Comment: I think I'm doing that. This just somehow stopped working magically. I feel like i put random keystrokes into a file somewhere or something :(

Comment: If it builds and runs, it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the build target as 'iOS Device'.
2. Select Product->Archive from the menu toolbar.
3. Click 'Next' and then select the file location.
4. Select '.ipa' and click 'Next'.
5. Select the location at which you would like to save the file. Click OK.
6. The file appears at the location selected above.

But, to build on an iOS Device you must have the proper certificates installed and appropriate  changes made under the Target heading.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and my solution was to completely exit xcode reopen and try the archive again, totally fixed. Must be a bug of some sort.