# Archives no longer displaying in organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I am trying to submit an update for my app to the app store. All of a sudden Archives are no longer showing up in the Archives section of the Organizer. Xcode says the Archive was successful with no errors, but it never displays...

Workflow:

```
1. Clean
2. Build for Archive
3. Archive
```

[image]

This article did not help me: [Archive does not appear in xcode4 organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280914/archive-does-not-appear-in-xcode4-organizer)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've resolved this issue, but I truly don't understand what happened. Xcode had asked me if I wanted to "upgrade to latest recommended settings and performing project clean up"; sounds great, right? Wrong.

After that is when my problems started. Thankfully it created a snapshot before it did this and I was able to restore back to it. I am now able to Archive just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This probably seems silly, but make sure the Reveal Archive in Organizer is checked in your scheme.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeArchive.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH6