# Can't archive a product

Tags: xcode, archive

I go to Product-->Archive and after archiving I get a message "Archive succeeded", but I can't see an archive in organiser. What's the problem? Thanks ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Archives not showing up in Organizer for XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have "Skip Install" set to YES in your build settings? If so, try NO.