# Resource for steps to put app onto physical iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have a PhoneGap application which works in the Xcode simulator. I also am in the Apple Developer Program so I can do code signing to run apps on actual devices.

However, I am having a hard time finding a good resource to walk me through the exact steps to get the app on my physical iPhone/iPad. I have found other guides which are either for Xcode 3, or they show how to get PhoneGap working in the emulator but not how to get on an actual device, or they are presumably using a different version of Xcode 4 because they reference different commands than I have.

If you have successfully deployed an application from Xcode 4 onto an iOS device, could you please post a link to steps that you used or refer a book that has that information? I appreciate any help that anyone can give on the subject. Thanks!

[Edit: Though I am using PhoneGap, the steps to deploy from Xcode to iOS device are AFAIK the same.]

[Edit to add more detail:

I have my project made and it runs on iPhone 4 simulator and iPad 4 simulator.

I also can plug in my iPad (already went through the assistant to get it provisioned), select it in the scheme list box, click the Run button and it will launch as expected on the iPad. Does this mean that I have the code signing part working at least?

So far so good. Now I want to make a build so that I can distribute to people to test the app on their devices (I have their UDIDs already). When I get to the "Publishing Your Application for Distribution" section of the iOS Development Guide in the iOS Developer Library, I get stuck in the Archiving Your Application for Testing section. I am having trouble finding the Code Signing Identity build setting. It also looks like they have changed the menus around because they refer to a Build > Build and Archive menu item that doesn't exist anymore. I tried Product > Build for > Build For Archiving which seems like the closest option and the build actually succeeds but in the Organizer > Archives tab there are no archives.

Sorry that I do not have more specific information about where the process is breaking down for me but I'm new to the Xcode environment. I can typically figure these things out on my own as long as there is documentation somewhere but I have not been able to find any that match my build of Xcode. Thanks!]

[Edit again: After doing more research I ended up following the suggestion of others and did a complete uninstall/reinstall of Xcode which ended up resolving the issue albeit in a rather heavy handed way.]

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to check out Apple's Documentation, for sure:

- [iOS Development Guide: Managing Devices and Digital Identities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2)
- [iOS Development Guide: Building and Running Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW13)

They have a complete walkthrough of provisioning, building, and deploying your application to a device.

The Xcode Organizer makes it fairly straight forward and painless now... but there are still some sticking points, and reading the documentation will give you a full overview of exactly what's going on in the process.

Comment: Thanks. I looked through those docs and the screen shots do not match my version of Xcode. I am using 4.0.2 and they have changed the interface so the documentation does not match my build of Xcode. Sorry, I should have specified that I was using 4.0.2.

Comment: The options are still pretty similar though. Is there a particular step you're having an issue with? Maybe I can help with a particular question?

Comment: Hi Steve, I appreciate the offer. I am starting over from scratch so I have a clean environment and I will post more specifics in a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to apple advise, setting Skip Install (Build Setting) to NO fixed this.  Using phone gap here.

[Archives not showing up in Organizer for XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your Apple Developer Account Credentials, You can follow gist I have created:

[Apple's Code Signing Process](https://gist.github.com/DalwadiV/2e43760d973c1d2baada)