# Xcode 5.1: Can't find archive on Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload an app update. The status on iTunes Connect is "Waiting For Upload". When I try to archive the app, I got the message "Build Succeeded" but Organizer does not show. If I open the Organizer window, I can see no archived app.

I tried editing the schemes but got no success so far.

[image: Scheme]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you created an app store provisioning profile, and archiving using that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer later in one of the answers to this question : [Archives not showing up in Organizer for Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4)

This is how I solved the problem:

> Set "Skip Install" to NO on your application target