# Xcode iOS distribution creates archive successfully but Archives is empty - why?

Tags: ios, xcode

OK I had to distribute an iOS application and have read stackoverflow ([especially this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4)) and apple guides carefully

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW1
- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html

I do have Xcode 6.3.1 set up with an iOS developer and distribution certificate - my Xcode preferences looks as follow:

[image: Xcode account preferences]

I have a real device connected and can do `Xcode > Product > Archive` which Archives successfully:

[image: Archive successful]

Perfect lets go to `Xcode > Organizer > Archives` and upload the application:

[image: Organizer > Archives is empty]

But the Archives is empty:

No Archives
   Use the Archive command within an Xcode project or import an archive from an Xcode Server bot.

Thats weird because Archive said it was successfully created and its even archive to

```
/Users/<my user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-05-20/MyApp 20-05-15 17.09.xcarchive
$ tree -L 1 <archive>

├── Products
│   └── Applications
└── dSYMs
    ├── BrightFutures.framework.dSYM
    ├── MyApp.app.dSYM
    └── Typhoon.framework.dSYM
```

OK lets open the `xcarchive` file directly - but this raises:

```
The archive could not be installed.
The archive may be corrupt or unreadable
```

Why? and how to solve this?

### Update 1

I got the archive build:

- removing and adding all my cocoapods and running `pods install` again (there is [some discussion going on about problems with cosigning](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3156) an error I also had randomly but did no include in my original question to keep the post as slim as possible)
- adding `Images.xcassets` to my xcode project it turned out it was an old xcode project with out such assets.

But it still doesn't taste as a real solution.

Comment: It's xcode, so I'll say this with the least amount of cynism : Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: what do you exactly mean with `it`?

Comment: XCode is a really bad IDE. Sometimes just restarting it + clean command fixes bugs.

Comment: OK thx for you suggestions I did that a couple of times during the try outs so I doubt thats a solution for the corrupted archive problem.

Comment: I tried uninstalling cocoapods, and even used different versions. I am now on 0.39.0 and i still have the same issue.

Comment: @kareem I can't reproduce the issue any longer I'm using Xcode 7.1.1 and pods: 0.39.0.rc.1. Your project could have problems with assets etc... I would try out with a vanilla ios project if I ever was hit but this issue again. Good luck...

Comment: @pellekrogholt okay i will try a new project thanks, dont think its my assets but will see too

Comment: I experience the same problem, I accidentally deleted two archives present in the archives organizer window, and I get the same window. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You might try unplugging your device and creating an archive with "iOS Device" selected as your build scheme.

Comment: OK thanks for that pointer. Even with device detached and `iOS Device` selected. I still had archive problems.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was slightly different in that in the past I had been able to generate archive's successfully, and then one commit, it stopped working. Turned out to be a caching issue, and while it your situation it sounds like you were able to simply `rm -rf Pods` to solve the issue, in my case, that was not enough, so maybe someone else will find this useful.

Here's what worked:

```
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf build
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

Hope this saves someone else like 14 hours.