# Xcode successfully archived application, but Archives Organizer does not list any

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, ios9, xcode7

The problem is - a project is built and archived without any error but the `Archives` section in Organizer is empty (at the same time  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` contains all generated archives).

I'm aware with this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4) but it's 4 years old and I've tried all offered there solutions (some of them are no longer relevant). I think it might be an Xcode7 related issue and wanted to enumerate all my targets and settings therefore someone who already has handled this bug/issue could find differences and help me out.

Here are the options from a `Build Settings/Deployment` section:

**Project:**

```
- Skip Install: Yes
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)
```

**Targets (5 items):**

iOS App:

```
- Skip Install: No
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)
```

iOS Framework:

```
- Skip Install: Yes
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

Watch App:

```
- Skip Install: No
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)
```

Watch Extension:

```
- Skip Install: Yes
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)
```

Watch Framework:

```
- Skip Install: Yes
- Installation Directory: $(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

I made all recommendation from this [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-XCODE_SUCCESSFULLY_ARCHIVED_MY_APPLICATION__BUT_THE_ARCHIVES_ORGANIZER_DOES_NOT_LIST_MY_ARCHIVE) ie:

1. Enabled `Reveal Archive in Organizer` option in the scheme Editor's Archive pane.
2. Tried various combinations of the `Skip Install` build setting (apps targets always are set to `No`).
3. `Version` and `Build` values are the same and equal "2.0.0" in my case.
4. An archive is created with a selected real device.
5. A project utilizes CocoaPods as a dependency manager but I'm not sure whether it might be an issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by performing 3 consecutive steps:

1. All files from Watch Framework have been moved directly to Watch Extension. After this archives started showing up in Organizer but in the `Other Items` section. To fix it the following 2 steps were performed.
2. For each CocoaPod in `Build Phases/Headers` all headers were moved from the `Public` to `Project` section.
3. For Watch App in the `Build Settings/Deployment` section the `Skip Install` parameter was switched to `Yes`.