# Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) - unable to see new archives being created in organiser

Tags: xcode

I have an application that I would like to release to the app store. I have created provisioning profiles, certificates etc and it all seems to be compiling correctly. When I try to distribute the application by Selecting a generic IOS device and then from the product menu --> archive. The build runs fine without error but I have not archives created. I have automatic code signing checked and I have verified that the archives are not being placed into `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`

I'm not sure what else I can try for this. Any help is appreciated.

Jimi

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the location Xcode saves archives into.

In the Xcode's Menu, go to *Xcode* -> *Preferences...* -> *Locations*

[image]

Comment: Very good, but won't do him any good if he sees nothing in Window -> Organizer.

Comment: I can see the files in documents. Do I just change this to point to the Library folder?

Comment: @Jimi I always use default location and it works fine. If you are saying that in your configuration Xcode saves archives to some other directory, this probably might be an issue for Organizer to locate those files. But I am not sure.