# xcode 14 shows "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier" when archiving IOS app, but I have set the bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I archive my IOS app, it builds successfully but it shows an error: "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier", the weird thing is that I have the bundle identifier set correctly in these places:

- info.plist
- General > Identity > Bundle Identifier
- Signing & Capabilities > Signing > Bundle Identifier

The main issue is that it says that the archive is successful but when I go to the organizer it doesn't show up, so I can't distribute the app. If I go the path where the archive is generated and try to open it, it says that the archive is corrupt. I believe this issue has to do with the error "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier". Archiving was something that used to work in xcode 13, but it hasn't worked the first time in xcode 14 in my project (even if I follow the same steps).

These are the steps I take.

1. I install dependencies using "npm i --legacy-peer-deps" (I use react-native)
2. Then go to ios directory and there install the pods: "npx pod-install"
3. I click: Product > Archive
4. Wait 1 or 2 minutes while it archives
5. Done

Once it finishes archiving it displays "Build Succeeded", but it also displays this error:

```
Archive Missing Bundle Identifier
Domain: IDEArchivedApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Archive content at path /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-07-04/beunik_employees 4-07-23, 2.42 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/beunik_employees.app is missing a bundle identifer.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-04 19:42:17 +0000";
}


System Information

macOS Version 13.2.1 (Build 22D68)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-07-04T14:42:17-05:00
```

I don't think it has to do with my provisioning profile since I archived a random project I downloaded from internet and used the same provisioning profile but this time it worked well, it didn't show that error. If it's of any use this is how it looks.

[image: Provisioning Profile]

I have tried several things as suggested by this thread: [Archives not showing up in Organizer for Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4) but nothing has worked:

- Made sure the check box for show in Organizer is checked.
- In the build settings switch Skip Install -> Release to NO, for the build settings used for archiving.

I also tried reinstalling xcode or restarting the computer but no luck.
I also tried rolling back the xcode version but my OS version doesn't allow me to do that.

If it's of any help here is my info.plist:

[image: info.plist]

What I need is to be able to archive the project, see the archive in the organizer and be able to distribute it.

Comment: We you able to fix this? if yes, how? @HangarRash

Comment: @RohithRaviTejaKilaparthi It's not my question, it was posted by Alex Rendón. See their answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, this can happen if you have Pre-actions in your in your scheme Archive settings. The solution was actually pretty simple:

1. Edit scheme
2. Go to Archive tab
3. Go to Pre-actions
4. In the dropdown "Provide build settings from" and set value to "None" to every script.
5. Done

This fixed it for me.