# Archive Missing Bundle Identifier Domain

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, bundle-identifier

I am currently trying to archive my Xcode project and it is giving me an error that says:

```
Archive Missing Bundle Identifier
Domain: IDEArchivedApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Archive content at path /Users/solar/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-12-27/Unity-iPhone 12-27-23, 9.04 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/merger game.app is missing a bundle identifer.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-12-28 02:04:15 +0000";
}
```

I have done very similar things to this question in regards to the bundle identifier, but their solution isn't working for me: [xcode 14 shows "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier" when archiving IOS app, but I have set the bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76615852/xcode-14-shows-archive-missing-bundle-identifier-when-archiving-ios-app-but-i)

When I try to edit the pre-actions, it doesn't give me anything. I have already archived this project once, but then I changed the version and the bundle identifier and now it doesn't work anymore(i changed it in both of the versions of info.plist). Please help!