# Xcode Archiving Build Error:Archive Missing Bundle Identifier Domain

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, bundle-identifier

I am currently trying to archive my Xcode project, but it gives me an error that says:

Archive Missing Bundle Identifier Domain: IDEArchivedApplicationErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Archive content at path /Users/solar/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-12-27/Unity-iPhone 12-27-23, 9.04 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/merger game.app is missing a bundle identifer. User Info: {     DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-12-28 02:04:15 +0000"; }

Can someone please help me find out what is going on? I tried editing the Info.plist files, the build settings (in both the project and the target), and the general tab. I also found someone with the same problem, who fixed it by deleting scheme pre-actions, but I didn't have any scheme actions for anything, let alone archiving(link:[xcode 14 shows "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier" when archiving IOS app, but I have set the bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76615852/xcode-14-shows-archive-missing-bundle-identifier-when-archiving-ios-app-but-i)). Please help me!