# iPhone App problem while creating AdHoc after adding new target for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, ad-hoc-distribution

In x-code4 I want to make Adhoc version (.ipa file of the project)
but after build and archive when i  press "Share" in organizer 
it is not showing option for selecting  ipa Package

previouly it was showing option when target was only ipohne

[image]
[image]

in other project i am able to select it as shown below

[image]
[image]

so what could be the problem ? what should I do to get option for making ipa file?

(i have also included coreplot-cocaTouch.xcodeproject to my app so it may creating problem?

in my project there are different xib fles for iphone and ipad so there are two targets in single project 
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of this question: [XCode4 + iOS 4.3: "No Packager exists for the type of archive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271496/xcode4-ios-4-3-no-packager-exists-for-the-type-of-archive)

You probably need to change your static libraries to "Skip Install".

Comment: I have tried with that but still I could not solve this problem

Comment: For me, it was not the highly rated, accepted answer in that linked question that solved the problem. It was the SECOND one, that had the bit about header files in the subproject. Check that out.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who might be having problems with this, here is a step by step of how I created an .ipa file after successfully adding CorePlot 0.9 to my project:

1) Click on your CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj in the Project Navigator (you have added a new project and targets to your main project, and you need to disable it from installing)

2) While in the "PROJECT" settings, click on the "Build Settings" tab, scroll to the "Deployment" section and find "Instalation Directory."  Delete whatever you have in that field (do not do any of this in your main project, only in your CorePlot project).

3) In the "Skip Install" section right below the Installation Directory section, set the "No" to "Yes" (make sure all build types are set to "Yes").

4) Now do all the same to all of the "TARGETS" (CorePlot-CocoaTouch, Documentation, and Universal Library).

5) Click on the "CorePlot-CocoaTouch" target, then click on the "Build Phases" tab.  You will see a section called "Copy Headers." Move all the headers in "Public" and "Private" sections to the "Project" section (just highlight/drag/drop all the .h files into the Project section)

6) Make sure you are set to build for iOS Device, then in the XCode options at the top of your screen, select Product > Archive.

7) Open Window > Organizer and select the "Archives" tab.  You will see your app there once it has finished building.  Select the archive, then click on the "Share" button.  You will see an option selected "iOS AppStore Package (.ipa)."  Click "Next," name your file "YourAppName.ipa" and choose where the file will be saved on your computer.

That should take care of creating an ipa when you are using the CorePlot framework.

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked perfectly for me with CorePlot 1.0.