# Create IPA file in Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0 Beta

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

How do I create a .ipa file in Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0 (Beta). I've already developed an application but I can not find an entitlement file. Can anyone tell me the procedure for creating a .ipa file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Xcode version 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0

Comment: There's already a [very good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive/5372142#5372142) to the possibly duplicate question of [Xcode 4: create IPA file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If u have apple developer certificate and corresponding provisional profile means it is easy to create .ipa file in XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 sdk.

```
      1) Select ios device in scheme.
      2) Archive your project.
      3) Select your archive in Organizer and share this.
      4) give url which u want to share and save your .ipa file to any location.
      5) .ipa and plist file will be create. upload these and make wireless distribution via html.
```

Comment: this video tutorial helped me create IPA with Xcode 4.2, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAykwTf6sDg ; though I couldn't understand the language :P