# Copying an ipa File From a Test iPhone to a Host Computer

Tags: ios, ipa, computer-forensics

To be honest:
I feel pretty dumb asking this question, as it seems to be one of the most basic tasks...

But all my searches so far did not yield a result, so here is my problem:

I have a test build of an app I am working on, that behaves...let's say: *special*.

In order to find out what exactly went wrong in our test rig, I want to inspect **all the files** in the ipa bundle, not only those Xcode let's me download.

The question is: how am I going to do that?

The filenames in the iTunes device-backup are all hashed and a quick `head -c 20 "$fileName";` over the directory listing was not very revealing, either...

Google's search results are infested with answers to the question "How do I get my stolen and cracked ipa **onto** a jailbroken device" and the questions I found here so far, all handle the direction from host computer to device as well.

PS:
Jailbreaking in order to ssh to the device is — of course — **not** an option.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can inspect the .ipa *before* you put it on the device - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive

Comment: Unfortunately, _before_ doesn't cut it... Anyway: I'm currently in the process of fixing the _cause_ of my situation by changing the build configuration of our Jenkins to append certain build parameters to the bundle-identifier in the Info.plist...

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but maybe [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org)'s [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd) can be of help since  it does not require a jailbreak.