# Potential Leak of an Object - Xcode - ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am using ios 5 with ARc enable. so in the following example I'm getting the memory leak warning...but since using ARC , i cant use autorelease. Please any suggestion anyone?

```
  -(void)coreImageEffect{
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:blurImage.image];
    CIFilter *hueAdjust = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];

    [hueAdjust setDefaults];
    [hueAdjust setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [hueAdjust setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 3.4f]
    forKey:@"inputAngle"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [hueAdjust valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    blurImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:
    [context createCGImage:outputImage
    fromRect:outputImage.extent]];

    }
```

I cannot use `[CIContext Autorelease]`;
the problem is showing CIContext "Method returns a core foundation object with a +1 retain count"

Please suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-createCGImage:…` returns a Core Graphics object which is not an Objective-C object and will not be managed by ARC. So you have to [CGImageRelease](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageRelease) it manually:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                   fromRect:outputImage.extent];
blurImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

but why not use [`+imageWithCIImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCIImage%3a) directly?

```
blurImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];
```

Comment: one more question Kenny: I want to send my Iphone app to some of my frnds for testing on their simulator, before i upload my project to itunes market. How can i do so? i have ios 5, xcode 4.2

There seems to be no option in this xcode through which i can send the .ipa file.

Someone also said me that adhoc distribution is the only obtion, but i believe, there's a easier way to do the same.

Comment: @RanajoyRoy: You could send them the source code if you don't want to go through Ad Hoc. For .ipa, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive.

Comment: @RanajoyRoy if KennyTM's answer solved your problem, you should accept his answer buy clicking the √.