# xcode 4.3.1 - Share archive option not visible

Tags: iphone, ipa, testflight

I am trying to put my build up for testing on TestFlightApp. In my previous version of xcode, I was able to view the "share" option after archiving, which I used to create the ipa file. The ipa file was uploaded to testflight and everything worked as expected. With the upgrade to xcode 4.3.1, I don't see the share option. I tried using the distribute option and created the ipa. Then when I tried uploading the ipa to testflight, got the following error.

'Invalid IPA: values for key com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier are mismatched between profile and binary'

can someone help.

Comment: Did you fix this in the end? I'm struggling at it now...

Comment: I just reinstalled Xcode 4.2 and did it from that (i had 4.3.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it.

`com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` is specifically for iCloud. See [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingiCloud/EnablingiCloud.html). So I used the following procedure:

1. Verify App ID in iOS provisioning Portal iCloud status (mine is enabled)
2. Removed old entitlements from project (I had manually created them)
3. Use the Target editor to enable the entitlements (at the bottom of the Target editor window), matching the App ID iCloud setting, added Container and Keychain Access.
4. Clean and Archive
5. Select the archive and click on Distribute...
6. Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment
7. Select your development code signing identity
8. Save the bundle to disk - did not check for enterprise
9. Drag ipa to TestFlightApp.com builds

At this point, TestFlight accepted the bundle and my testers were able to download!

Comment: It is very important to add the container, which isn't added by default when you select "Enable Entitlements". Once the container was added (com.company.app) the build uploaded just fine to TestFlight.

Comment: But why when I clicked "Distribute", there is no such option "Save for enterprise ..."? The only two options are "Save Built Products" and "Export as Xcode Archive". I am on Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned by Kent and it worked like a charm. The missing part in my case was the set up on the provisioning portal. I had to remove old entitlements. Thank you.

Comment: Same problem as Yuchen has. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just checked, my version if Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002). Try: (1) Xcode, Create new project (I used tabbed app), you do not need to change anything. (2) Attach device. (3) Run, it should run cleanly. (3) Product -> Archive. I now have "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" as the second option in the "Select the method of distribution" dialog box. If it works in this _clean_ project, it may be one of your build settings in your project.

Answer (score 5):

I know an answer has been provided to this question, but looking at the comments (and my own request having sending me here also) it seems that help might be needed to those like @Yuchen or @Kent in the comments that only have two options in the distribute panel ("Submit to the iOS App Store" and "Export as Xcode Archive"), and can't see the "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" option.

If your target includes other targets (e.g. libraries), you should put the "Skip Install" flag to YES in the "sub" target Build settings. This will allow yourself to distribute your archive as an IPA file.

More information can be found on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372142/1309733).

Hope this will help,
Thibault

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4.3.1 there is no "share" option in Archives tab of Organizer to create IPA.

Hence to create IPA just click the available "Distribute" option and select Method - "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" then we have an option to save the build in IPA format.

See the Attached Screen Shots,

[image]

thanks,
Naveen Shan

Comment: any idea why "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" option is absent from the options? I see only "Save Built Products" and "Export as Xcode Archive" on my XCode 4.3.1

Comment: answering my own comment question, it was the files listed under "Private" of the "Copy Headers" section https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Xcode-4-Archiving-Issue:--'Does-not-contain-a-single-bundle'

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`Distribute...`   and   `Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment`

It is same as the old `Share...` menu.