# Xcode 4.3 - make archive for ad hoc testing not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

In Xcode 4.2 I used the Share option to create an .ipa file and send it via e-mail to my friend for testing. In Xcode 4.3 this option is gone. there is now the 'Save for enterprise or ad hoc distribution' option instead. When I choose this option and do the code signing, I get an ipa file but this app does NOT work. It is possible to install it using itunes but it only shows the default screen and then crashes.

What's different now in xcode 4.3?

I am using the same provisioning profile as before(a developers profile). After a few attepmts, I tried to change the app signing profile/certificate to the distribution profile but nothing worked. When I searched StackOF for similar questions, I saw that people put their plist somewhere with the ipa file. I didn't do that before and it was working. The only change from my point of view is the scode version(I was using xcode 4.2) and the fact that there is no 'Share' option anymore.

Please help!

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642252/xcode-4-3-1-share-archive-option-not-visible

Comment: Well, may be but that question/answer did not solve the issue :-/

Comment: Ok :(. Have you tried uninstall the app on the device before installing it ?

Comment: Yes, several times :-/
I deleted it from itunes, iphone and installed it again and agian with different signing profiles. The funny part is that it shows no errors when installing, which happened a lot when I signed it wrong, but this is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may be the repetition of [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642252/xcode-4-3-1-share-archive-option-not-visible/9766989#9766989)

See the Answer in that question.

Here also I paste the answer again,

In Xcode 4.3.1 there is no "share" option in Archives tab of Organizer to create IPA.

Hence to create IPA just click the available "Distribute" option and select Method - "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" then we have an option to save the build in IPA format.

thanks,
Naveen Shan

Comment: hi, Naveen, thanks for your response! I've seen that answer but my actual problem was elsewhere. I deleted a nib file that was not needed but did not delete the reference to it in some hidden file. The app worked fine on my device because it cashed the nib but when I cleaned the project, the same error appeared on my test device. So xcode 4.3 was not to blame, it was me :)
But thanks for your input and since you're the only one to answer, I'll set you answer as right! Regards!

Comment: But why when I clicked "Distribute", there is no such option "Save for enterprise ..."? The only two options are "Save Built Products" and "Export as Xcode Archive". I am on Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: @Yuchen Mine also only has these two options - did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Hey commenters, follow this: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237 I just did it. The key is to make sure you hit "Skip install" ONLY on the library, NOT your project. (Pay attention to the columns, that's what fixed it for me)

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered, but I ran into the same problem today: I was unable to get ad-hoc apps to install over the air in XCode 4.3, when it worked perfectly fine in 4.2.

What ended up working for me was to **not check** the "Save for Enterprise Distribution" box and instead save the .ipa file straight to disk. That file installed fine on my device via iTunes and by making my own .plist file (duplicating the xml schema from a previous build), I was able to get over-the-air working again.

I noted when doing the "Save for Enterprise Distribution" process that the .ipa file got generated with an incorrect url (it was linking back to itself). But even when fixing that mistake, the app would still not install (it would download, but not install). I can only imagine that the problem is in the .ipa.

Hopefully this will save someone else some time and aggravation.