# testing iphone apps built on a remote mac

Tags: iphone, windows, device

I'm using macincloud service to try/play/learn about building iPhone apps. I have a dummy app, and I'll like to test it on my real device.

I've got the developer certificate, I've installed the profiles, but now I'll like to test my app on a real device. Because it is not possible to connect my iPhone to the macincloud servie and because I'm on a windows machine, how can I test my app on a real device(the one with UDID that was used in generating the certificates and provisioning profiles).

Is there any file that xCode is generating and it can be used to transfer on a real device from a Win7 machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate an archive in XCode, and then from the organizer click "Share" to generate an IPA file.  This file along with the ad-hoc provisioning profile can install the app on a provisioned device via iTunes on a Mac or a Windows machine.

For info on provisioning your device for ad-hoc deployment, see here:  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices or the apple developer docs.

Good Luck.

Comment: Here's a good description on how to generate an ipa file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive

Comment: Btw, take note of the answer's fifth comment that "Share" is now "Distribute", etc. (at least in XCode 4.5).

Answer (score 4):

Correct answers have been given already. However, have a look at http://testflightapp.com . That might come handy when you go for more test devices especially when you want to distribute it to a beta testing community.

Comment: A very enthusiastic up vote on this.  We use testflight a lot and it has dramatically simplified our distribution process.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an Ad-Hoc build.  You will have to read Apple's docs to see whats involved.  Then you will have an app file you can install with any iTunes.