# xcode distributing application with 2 project

Tags: xcode

i have a problem to distributing application with 2 project (one project with sub-project include inside). When i try to make as usual "archive", i'm not able to send application. 
Could someone help me?
Regards

Comment: You'll need to give some more details on what's not working and what error messages if any you're receiving.

Comment: My schema of my project is like this: MyApp is my project name. I add inside another project: otherApp.xcodeproj. When i try to make Archive to delivery the app to Apple Store, in the organizer identify my project like an "Generic Xcode Archive" and not like "iOS App Archive"

Comment: This question and its answer is also valid for archiving Mac applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the sub-project is a library? And when you do Build > Archive you get an .xcarchive file instead of a .ipa? If so, you need to set the Skip Install flag to No on your library (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372142/263871)), then Build > Archive will generate a .ipa file.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as the correct one in that case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you have two projects. 
For the sub-project you need to edit the **Target > Build** Settings and **set the Skip Install setting to Yes.** 
Afterwards the "Archive" action will work as usual.