# XCode app not syncing to itunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, ipa

I created an app on Xcode and synced it to iPhone and it works fine. Now, i want to sync the app to iTunes so that i can copy the ipa file and send it to someone else for testing.
But the app is not getting synced to iTunes.

Is there any way to get the ipa file?
My app uses sqlite database. Is that the reason for not getting the app synced?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Build a app. And you will get a .app

2) Open iTunes

3) Drag and drop a .app to the iTunes at left panel on top. For truely drop, you must see a Green "+" about cursor when you are draged a .app on panel.

4) iTunes will convert your .app to .ipa file

5) Look at Users/{you}/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications folder and find your IPA app file

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over thinking this one, instead of deploying to your phone then syncing back to iTunes, try archiving your app, then making an ad-hoc distribution. This will give you the IPA

[image]

[image]

Now, I'm not completely sure about this but Apple may have specifically put protocols in place to keep your from making your own ad-hocs your the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode go to Product->Archive. After the Archive operation completes, go to the Organizer, select your archive, select Share and in the "Select the content and options for sharing:" pane set Contents to "iOS App Store Package (.ipa) and Identity to iPhone Distribution (which should match your ad hoc/app store provisioning profile for the project).

Comment: i dont have a developer account yet... any method to create an ipa file without the account??

Comment: you can't run the app on device without having developer account.