# Compile Source Xcode to send Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I need to send off an iPhone app Xcode project to a agency but I do not want them to be able to see the source code of the project, how do I compile the project and send that to the agency so they are able to submit the project to Apple but not see the source code?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Why wouldn't you want them to see the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create archive file and send that instead of sending Xcode code.

You can check this thread and get to know how you can create archive file (ipa file)- [Xcode 4: create IPA file instead of .xcarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive/5372142#5372142)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build the project for archiving
in Xcode navigate to `Product -> build for -> archiving`

this will produce an app file, that you will send to the agency

However note that you will need to get the provision and keys to be able to build for distributing