# TestFlight Fails to create IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm using XCode 4.4.1 to create an IPA file for TestFlight AdHoc Distribution.  If I go through the Organizer to create the IPA file, everything works great and TestFlight just works.

Here's the problem.  If instead of using the Organizer to create the IPA, I allow TestFlight Co-Pilot to detect the new archive, I get a popup that TestFlight has noticed the new Archive, and I click the "Upload" button.  But then, I get an error that the IPA file could not be created.  The error appears to have something to do with signatures, but I'm using the same signatures as I do when creating the IPA though XCode's Organizer.  Here's a screenshot of the actual error. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

[image: TestFlight error screenshot]

Comment: Does your build produce more than one target?

Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive/5372142#5372142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting TestFlight support, I was finally to get it working.  Try this in a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the installation of Xcode 4.5.

The solution was to install "**Command Line Tools**".

```
Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools
```

Comment: The Command Line Tools download no longer appears there in 6.1.  Instead, you can use "xcode-select --install" on the command line, which will prompt you to install them.