# Xcode compile program once and install to multiple devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compilation

When I press Build and Go - my program is being recompiled then send to iOS device - so if I need to install it to 2 or 3 devices - the checksum will vary. I need to have one binary for all the same devices - how could I do that - compile once and install on several devices this binary.

Comment: Some detailed instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive

Answer (score 0):

Do use TestFlight (https://testflightapp.com) or HockeyApp (http://www.hockeyapp.net). This allows you to distribute your app OTA (Over the Air), catch crash logs, symbolicate them, force users to update to specific version, ...

To do this, you have to put all devices into provisioning profile. When you do this, you're not forced to build and install it separately for each device, because the app is already signed for devices in your provisioning profile. Thus you can also simply grab the IPA drop it to iTunes and sync for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all your devices to your [provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action). Then you can create `.ipa` file containing your prebuilt app with Xcode and just distribute it to be installed using iTunes.