# Issue in Archiving of Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20, mailcore

I am using `Product > Archive` of iPad project When I am using the build Configuration as release in my project, I got succeed to get the file in the organizer, but it does not show the Version, identifier and icon image rather it made the file having `.xcarchieve` extension showing icon image of gray color written Archive on it with symbol A. And When I use the `Build Configuration` of my project as `Distribution` It some times show me the Error:

```
"Three20/Three20.h" File not Found
```

And Some times show me the error of ::

```
Command/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1..
```

My Project has 2 static libraries Three20 and MailCore Framework.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Is `Skip Install` set to YES on your library targets? See accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive)

Comment: Ok.. Yes I have done Skip Install to yes in both static libraries.