# Xcode organizer .ipa file not showing normal options

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ipa

I'm Developing application which using some of `cocos2d` animations. So i imported the `cocos2d project` into my `Xcode`. But when i give `Product -> Archive` i'm getting following screen. Like, `Save Built Products` and `Export as Xcode Archive`
[image]

I could not get normal option for my `Archive`. Can anyone help me to find what i'm doing wrong.
I found its happening because, **multiple targets** in my projects. I removed all **Targets** except my project target from `Manage Schemes`. But still i'm getting `.archive` file in `organizer` with same options. If i remove those target from my project i'm getting error like following

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, by removing `cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj` and i added the folders what are all i needed. I tried same thing, but before i added all my files in `cocos2d project folder`. I got answer from this [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21293). Following folder are i added from the `cocos2d` **folder**

```
 - cocos2d
 - CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion
 - CocosDenshion/CocosDenshionExtras
 - external/kazmath
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the build settings for the cocos2d project. Change `Skip Install Flags` to `YES`.

More info here, [Xcode 4: create IPA file instead of .xcarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive)