# Release to the App Store from an xcarchive

Tags: ios, app-store

If I was provided with an xcarchive, what steps would I follow to deploy it to the App Store?
The xcarchive is already signed with the proper credentials for the App Store.

Comment: This would be an excellent question for the person who gave you the archive.

Answer (score 1):

In finder press SHFT+CMD+G  and type this

```
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
```

Place your .xcarchive inside Archives folder

Restart Xcode, goto Xcode->Organizor. Next steps as usual..Validate § Upload.

**“ Just wondering why someone copied and sent xcarchive instead of uploading directly to the  AppSore by 2-3 clicks !!"**

Comment: Thanks for the help, Guru. Unfortunately, when I paste the archive into that folder and restart Xcode, I don't see the archive in organizer. I've also tried placing it in an appropriately named folder (with the date as the folder name). Do you have any idea why the archive wouldn't be appearing in Organizer?

Comment: not sure why not working...Instead you can generate ipa ? use application loader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive

Comment: I ended up generating an ipa and using application loader. Thanks for the help!