# Building apps that will run under ios7 from xcode 4.2 ios 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Extremely new to the xcode / ios world, so I apologise in advance .....

My dev machine is an old mac-mini running Snow Leopard and xcode 4.2

I have built an executeable that I want to put on my ipad, which is running at ios7.

In xcode, I did all the provisioning stuff and I see the following message :

> The version of iOS on "Daves iPad" does not match any of the versions
>   of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS
>   SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below,
>   or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK

I'm not sure I can ( or want ) to do either of these things. As far as I know xcode5 won't run on my machine, and I don't really want to downgrade my iPad to ios 5

Am I missing the point? Should I expect to be able to run ios5 executeables under ios7? If I should, how do I get them on to the ipad?

Comment: I was writing an answer that suggests you use Apple Configurator, but even that does not run on Snow Leopard. Maybe your best bet is to upgrade your OS.

Comment: I think that unfortunately if I upgrade the OS, I have to buy a new mac :(

Comment: Have you ever downloaded and installed one of the Xcode 5 Betas after WWDC? If you have, there may be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @EnricoSusatyo - I am _very_ new to all this. What's WWDC?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run iOS 5 executables on iOS 7, but you can't run a debug session on an iOS 7 device from anything older than Xcode 4.6.3.

I think the best you're  going to be able to do is to build the app, package it into an IPA, then install it on your device and run it from iTunes.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan C : The situation is complicated somewhat by me using the LiveCode development environment. It builds an iOS executeable. Do you know where I can find instructions of how to package it to an IPA, and install it on the device? I'm finding the online resources extremely hard to get a foothold on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create .ipa file from xcode, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372142/886276). But before that you should have installed provision profile for app distribution. Your testing devices should be listed there in iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution) on *Apple Developer Member center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.*