# How to import created a Xcode project in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i am created and successfully running a some project in Xcode from Mac.I am thought to this project was running in my iPhone.How to i am import this Xcode project from iPhone.Please help me

Comment: You need to be a registered Apple Developer to run a project in your phone. Otherwise, just use the simulator.

Comment: Sorry buddy's jam own thinking and exiting this program

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apple Developer Account, then:

1- You need to create few certificates, get info from [Distributing iOS Apps With iTunes Connect](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-ios-apps-with-itunes-connect--cms-21672)

2. If you don't have developer account, then you would have to purchase from [Apple Developer Program for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

Otherwise it will not be possible to run it on real devices, you can just check your app on simulator.

Read this detailed tutorial on [How to Test Your App on an iOS Device](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861)

Answer (score 0):

Connect phone via usb and wait umtil Xcode detects it. Then play app.

If you want to import an `ipa` file, to execute in another device, create a cert with imei of the phone, archive the app and import it. [Further info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive).